# Vanilla Javascript .fadein() .fadeOut() without JQuery

Tags: javascript

I am developing for IE10+ so i decided not to use JQuery. I write custom javascript function to Select, Fadein, FadeOut etc and it is working fine.
but i like to use the Function in JQuery Style (Object.fadeIn(), Object.FadeOut() etc).

Instead of JQuery Selector i use this.

```
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
```

When i need to select a Dom object i use this.

```
var myButton = _("button");
```

When i need to fadeIn Or fadeOut any object i use this.

```
function fade(type, ms, el) {
  var isIn = type === 'in',
    opacity = isIn ? 0 : 1,
    interval = 50,
    duration = ms,
    gap = interval / duration;

  if(isIn) {
    el.style.display = 'inline';
    el.style.opacity = opacity;
  }

  function func() {
    opacity = isIn ? opacity + gap : opacity - gap;
    el.style.opacity = opacity;

    if(opacity <= 0) el.style.display = 'none'
    if(opacity <= 0 || opacity >= 1) window.clearInterval(fading);
  }

  var fading = window.setInterval(func, interval);

}
```

Here is the specific code to fade my button

```
fade('out', 500, myButton);
```

I like to use like this `_( "myButton" ).fadeIn( 100 );`

> Update: The trick was to use prototype function for "-" to add additional
>   functionality like fadein(), fadeOut() .

Comment: _When we develop for IE10+ we really need JQuery?_ -- Yes.  We always need jQuery.

Comment: What is the question here?  Is this working code that you're asking for feedback on?  Or are there specific problems with it?

Comment: I like to use like this _( "myButton" ).fadeIn( 100 ); @jfriend00

Comment: FYI, your animation function is not adaptive at all.  It assumes intervals are always called on time and your animation will not always finish on time.  The more usual way to do this is to record the start time and then on each tick to calculate the desired opacity value based on the percentage of time elapsed so far.  This can be coded to then always finish on time.

Comment: And, what is the question?   There's still no explicit question I can find here.

Comment: @DavidR. Why we need JQuery always? All i need is to fade an object. i am developing for IE10+, my code is now only few bytes!! :)

Comment: Why not use CSS3 animations instead and get rid of all this code?

Comment: Take a look here http://youmightnotneedjquery.com

Comment: @jfriend00 It is a JS app, i need to fade the object when some conditions came true.  also  need to use .fadeIn or .fadeOut over and over again in many times, so i think this is the better way to do it,,,

Comment: There's no reason you can't have a small piece of JS that triggers a CSS3 transition that would animate the opacity and would do it with less code, less use of the CPU and less blocking of the JS thread and could be called as many times as you want. If you think otherwise, then that's only because you don't understand how to use a CSS3 transition.

Comment: @jfriend00 Actually i am learning by creating my app :) . I think CSS3  transition is much better, Now i am trying to implement the same.

Comment: @jfriend00 How can we use css3+js for the same?. Please show me an example.

Comment: @Vishnu - Since this question is pretty much done and more than a month old, I'd suggest you ask a new question about how to do this using CSS3 transitions.  You can address a comment to me with a link to the new question and I will then see it.

Comment: @jfriend00 please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835878/vanilla-javascript-fadein-fadeout-using-css3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
function _(el) {
  if (!(this instanceof _)) {
    return new _(el);
  }
  this.el = document.getElementById(el);
}

_.prototype.fade = function fade(type, ms) {
  var isIn = type === 'in',
    opacity = isIn ? 0 : 1,
    interval = 50,
    duration = ms,
    gap = interval / duration,
    self = this;

  if(isIn) {
    self.el.style.display = 'inline';
    self.el.style.opacity = opacity;
  }

  function func() {
    opacity = isIn ? opacity + gap : opacity - gap;
    self.el.style.opacity = opacity;

    if(opacity <= 0) self.el.style.display = 'none'
    if(opacity <= 0 || opacity >= 1) window.clearInterval(fading);
  }

  var fading = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

_('myButton').fade('out', 500);
```

From here on out you can extend your `_` object with any jQuery-like function.