# Smooth changing text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add some automatically changing text every minute in my website. I am happy with my code, but I want smoother animation, so the content appears and disappears more slowly. Any ideas?

```js
var cit = new Array(" Cool APP", " Best App ", " Love this App", " So good ");
var author = new Array("Matt"," Laz ","SoSo","JoJo");
var ind= 0;
function ChangeText(){
  document.getElementById('Citation').innerHTML = cit[ind];
  document.getElementById('author').innerHTML = author[ind];          
  if(ind < cit.length - 1 ){
    ind++;
  }else{
    ind = 0;
  }
  setTimeout("ChangeText();", 400);
}
ChangeText();
```

```html
<p id = "Citation">
</p>
<p id = "author">
</p>
```

Comment: You should use JQuery animation

Comment: What kind of animation? You can set a marquee behaviour, a fade in - fade out, fade in - fade out with position absolute....

Comment: It's a bit tricky. If you want one text to fade out, and after it's gone, to get the new text to fade in, it's easy. If you want the text to simultaneously fade in and out while overflowing one over the other, that'll be a bit more complicated. What is it exactly you are going for?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Hi Narxx! Yes, I want each text to be replaced by an another one but in smooth way!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vanilla Javascript .fadein() .fadeOut() without JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206054/vanilla-javascript-fadein-fadeout-without-jquery)

Comment: That question linked for a possible duplicate was closed as unclear -- but this question, to me anyway, is clear (especially with the help of the comments). Additionally, the OP of the possible duplication appears to be looking for Javascript to develop a fadeout/in methods. Here CSS looks applicable, so the answers are different (though both would work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of some css transitions and expand your javascript and html to get the desired functionality. Code below the following text description.

With css we can tell the browser to change certain properties with different animation techniques (`ease-in`, `ease-out`, etc.) over target durations of time. The following defaults to an `ease` transition, over 1 second, targeting any `opacity` changes to a given element that adheres to the css selector/rule (see [w3 schools transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for more).

```
transition: opacity 1s;
```

Now for the setting up the html/javascript to make use of transitions. We'll want to make some html elements that will be toggled back and forth with the next citation/author. These will essentially be faded-in/out as we increment our target citation/author. We'll need to make use of some absolute positioning so that the elements overlap, we'll need the help of some containing divs to get the job done (see HTML and css below, note I'm doing 1 second transitions).

After defining our HTML, we have to update the javascript to set the innerHTML of both the next and original curations/authors (see updated `ChangeCitation1()` and `ChangeCitation2()` methods below, note the 2 second delay to toggling the text, for you this would be set to perhaps 60s in production).

Basically we have a toggle function that sets the curations/authors and curations/authors on deck and flips the opacity back, infinitely. With fades of 1 second, and a changing of the text every 2 seconds.

```js
var cit = new Array(" Cool APP", " Best App ", " Love this App", " So good ");
var author = new Array("Matt"," Laz ","SoSo","JoJo");
var ind= 0;
document.getElementById('Citation1').innerHTML = cit[ind];
document.getElementById('Author1').innerHTML = author[ind]; 
ChangeCitation2();
function ChangeCitation2(){
  incrementIndex()
  document.getElementById('Citation2').innerHTML = cit[ind];
  document.getElementById('Author2').innerHTML = author[ind]; 
  document.getElementById('Citation1').style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById('Author1').style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById('Citation2').style.opacity = 1;
  document.getElementById('Author2').style.opacity = 1;
  setTimeout(ChangeCitation1, 2000);
}
function ChangeCitation1(){
  incrementIndex();
  document.getElementById('Citation1').innerHTML = cit[ind];
  document.getElementById('Author1').innerHTML = author[ind];
  document.getElementById('Citation1').style.opacity = 1;
  document.getElementById('Author1').style.opacity = 1;
  document.getElementById('Citation2').style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById('Author2').style.opacity = 0;
  setTimeout(ChangeCitation2, 2000);
}
function incrementIndex(){
  if(ind < cit.length - 1 ){
    ind++;
  }else{
    ind = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#Citation1, #Author1{
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
#Citation2, #Author2{
    transition: opacity 1s;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    margin-top:0px
}
#citationContainer, #authorContainer{
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="citationContainer">
    <p id = "Citation1"></p>
    <p id = "Citation2"></p>
</div>
<div id="authorContainer">
    <p id = "Author1"></p>
    <p id = "Author2"></p>
</div>
```

You could probably expand the following to use the psuedo element `::before` or `::after`, and manipulate it's `content` in the css... but this is a good starting place for you to dig into!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a LOT!